# Selenium ChromeDriver not Loading

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

Does anyone have a solution for this **[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYCnx.png)**?

The driver is instantiated and the browser is opened, but then I get the following error:

> [01:53:15,339] INFO  [CheckOut-0] - ####### Test 'MyTestCases.CheckOut' started
>   Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248304) on port 17682
>   May 26, 2017 1:53:16 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
>   [0.183][WARNING]: PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
>   May 26, 2017 1:53:18 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
>   [01:53:20,832] INFO  [CheckOut-0] - ####### Test 'MyTestCases.CheckOut' finished after 5491 ms
>   [01:53:20,838] INFO  [CheckOut-0] - Cleaning up ...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvC6N.png)

Comment: Do you start the chrome instance with any extensions?

Comment: no , i run it on linux throw config  data in the project.

Comment: Can you consider showing us the `_openHomePage` file. Thanks

Comment: Do update us your Selenium, ChromeDriver & Chrome version please. Thanks

Comment: Driver is version 2.2  from here https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html ,  iam using  this Framework  https://www.xceptance.com/en/xlt/     which uses Selenium  and this is the version of my browser Chromium 58.0.3029.110 Fedora Project

Comment: I suppose you should consider updating your ChromeDriver to the latest version of 2.29 for further analysis. Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB  see the link in the buttom  for _OpenHomePage

Comment: version 2.9  didn't work also. it worked at first but now this new issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found Solution  for the Problem. I had Old Libraries and replaced it with Selenium Libraries from  [Here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) and it worked.